# Reduce the distance between points

Tags: r, distance

I need to reduce the area of my graph and need to bring the flood and ebb closer together along with the associated points

[image: enter code here]

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Could you please provide some actual code to maximize you chances of receiving a quick reply? I would recommend the following [guideline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: I think what you need to do is adjust the y axis range on your plot. When you create the plot, try adding the parameter `ylim = c(-0.02, 0.08)`